# Problem with saving image from google streetview api in nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-api, get

I have the following code in nodejs. When making the call with postman, I get the expected result.

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const fs = require('fs');


function getStreetViewImage(address) {
  const KEY = [API KEY];
  const SIZE = '600x400';

  let params = {
    'location': address,
    'key': KEY,
    'size': SIZE
  };

  var options = {
    uri: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview',
    qs: params,
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
    },
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
  }

  request(options)
  .then(function (data) {
     const buffer = Buffer.from(data.body, 'utf8');
     fs.writeFileSync('image.jpeg', buffer);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err.toString());
  });

}
```

The content type and length in data.headers matches what is returned by postman.
When opening the resulting file however, there is an error with the image and nothing is displayed. If I encode the image to base64 and try to decode that string I also get an error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong... Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on a similar problem as we speak. A solution that (partly) works for me is:

```
const request = require('request-promise-native');
const fs = require('fs');
...
let options =
{
  method: "GET",
  url: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview`,
  qs: {
    key: '[API KEY]',
    size: '400x300',
    location: `address`
  },
  "Accept-Charset": "utf-8", // don't know if this is important
  json: true
};

await request(options).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('streetview.jpg', { flags: 'w' })); // overwrite
```

This creates the image file, but in my case the problem is that the `await` returns before the file is properly closed. The code after the `await` then (usually) finds a file of zero-length. I have not yet found a solution to that. I tried it by rewriting the above as:

```
try
{
  let stream = fs.createWriteStream('streetview.jpg', { flags: 'w', encoding: ???? });

  stream.on('finish', async () =>
  {
    // rest of my code after the file is properly closed
  });

  stream.write(await request(options));
  stream.end(); // flush file buffer and close the file
}
catch (err)
{
  ...
}
```

But what happens now is that, although `streetview.jpg` is created, it does not appear to be a valid `.jpg`-file anymore. I tried to solve this by trying several encodings in the place of the `????` in the code, but without any luck sofar. I do not have a lot of experience with `createWriteStream`, so there may be a simple solution to this (?).

I also found at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#map-parameters that you can specify a `format` parameter in the options object, and tried `png`, but that did not work either (the link states that this is the default format, which is not true).

Regards, John Pool

Comment: Thanks for that. My end goal was to have a base64 encoded string of the image and I was able to achieve that with your answer :)